# Retrieve user playlist using YouTube API

Tags: asp.net, .net, youtube, youtube-api

I have this code at the moment that authenticates a user and tries to retrieve the current authenticated users playlist but the request is inavlid and the error is as so

Execution of request failed:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/xx_xxx_x@hotmail.com/playlists

```
Public Function GetRequest(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As YouTubeRequest
  Dim youtubeSettings = New YouTubeRequestSettings("test", DeveloperKey, username, password)
  Dim youtubeRequest As New YouTubeRequest(youtubeSettings)
  Return youtubeRequest
End Function

Public Function GetUserPlaylists(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
  Dim youtubeRequest As YouTubeRequest = Me.GetRequest(username, password)
  Try
    Dim userPlaylists As Feed(Of Playlist) = youtubeRequest.GetPlaylistsFeed(username)

    If True Then
    End If
  Catch ex As Exception
  End Try
End Function
```

Comment: could it be to do with the username because it uses specific characters, maybe i need to urlencode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim youtubeRequest As YouTubeRequest = Me.GetRequest(username, password)

        Dim url As String = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists?v=2"

        Try

            Dim feedQuery As New FeedQuery(url)
            Dim userPlaylists As Feed(Of Playlist) = youtubeRequest.Get(Of Playlist)(feedQuery)

            If True Then

            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Function
```